# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' django

Tags: django, django-views

I get the above error when I call the custom view method,

```
#views.py

class MyEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    review_template = 'admin/polls/myentry/review.html'

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyEntryAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
             (r'\d+/review/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.review)),
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def review(self, request, id):
        entry = MyEntry.objects.get(pk=id)

        return render_to_response(self.review_template, {
            'title': 'Review entry: %s' % entry.title,
            'entry': entry,
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'root_path': self.admin_site.root_path,
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

admin.site.register(MyEntry, MyEntryAdmin)

#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views'
    url(r'^myentry/(?P<pk>\d+)/review/$', 'MyEntryAdmin', name='review')
)
```

When I call the url `http://localhost:8000/admin/polls/myentry/1/review/` I get the error

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Traceback:    
Environment:  
Request Method: GET
Request URL: `http://localhost:8000/admin/polls/myentry/1/review/`

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
    ('django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls')
Installed Middleware:
    ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/sun1/projectFolder/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/polls/myentry/1/review/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
```

Comment: do you have a relevant trace for the error?

Comment: Interesting. Could the use of `pk` in urls.py (last part of your code) be the issue?

Comment: I tried to change it to something like 'myentry_id', but still got the error.  I am following the blog post to create a admin view http://patrick.arminio.info/blog/2010/05/additional-admin-views/

Answer (score 0):

You don't use your ModelAdmin class itself as the destination of the URL pattern. The ModelAdmin class is registered with your existing admin, so its `get_urls` method is called and the relevant URLs are added to the default admin ones.

Remove that line from urls.py and it should work.

Comment: I removed that line in urls.py but I get this error - review() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: You're missing the parentheses round the \d+ in the regex in get_urls. It should be the same as the one you had in urls.py (minus the prefix).

Comment: Sorry now I get the error, review() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk',
 after I changed to  (r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/review/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.review)),   Thanks for your help

Comment: Come on, you should be able to debug this yourself. You are passing the argument pk, but the view is expecting id. Change one or the other.